# Is GStreamer available for Ubuntu 21.04, and if it is, then how to install it?

Tags: package-management, gstreamer

My first attempt to install GStreamer on Ubuntu 21.04 looks like this:

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo apt install gstreamer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gstreamer
```

Because that didn't work, therefor I visited the GStreamer webpage for installation on Linux:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c.
As instructed on the aforementioned webpage, my second attempt at GStreamer installation looks like this:

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package gstreamer1.0-doc is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gstreamer1.0-doc' has no installation candidate
```

What procedure enables the installation of GStreamer on Ubuntu 21.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use partial name of source code package.

Please visit relevant [search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gstreamer&searchon=sourcenames&suite=hirsute&section=all) [results](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=hirsute&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gst-plugins&searchon=sourcenames) on *packages.ubuntu.com* and choose correct binary package names which suite your needs.

If you know the name of relevant pkg-config/pkgconfig configuration file, then you can use file-search on the [same](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=hirsute&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=gstreamer%20pc) [site](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=hirsute&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=gstreamer-1.0.pc&searchon=contents).

The following installation commands look reasonable:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-dev
```