# Install gstreamer1.0-doc on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 64 for installing midieditor_3.3.0-1-amd64.deb

Tags: gstreamer

Trying to install MidiEditor, I got dependencies not resolved.

```
vincent@vincent-laptop:~/Applications/MidiEditor$ sudo dpkg -i midieditor_3.3.0-1-amd64.deb
Sélection du paquet midieditor précédemment désélectionné.
(Lecture de la base de données... 500571 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Préparation du dépaquetage de midieditor_3.3.0-1-amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de midieditor (3.3.0-1) ...
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de midieditor :
 midieditor dépend de qtdeclarative5-dev ; cependant :
  Le paquet qtdeclarative5-dev n'est pas installé.
 midieditor dépend de libqt5webkit5-dev ; cependant :
  Le paquet libqt5webkit5-dev n'est pas installé.
 midieditor dépend de qt5-default ; cependant :
  Le paquet qt5-default n'est pas installé.
 midieditor dépend de libqt5multimedia5-plugins ; cependant :
  Le paquet libqt5multimedia5-plugins n'est pas installé.
 midieditor dépend de gstreamer1.0-doc ; cependant :
  Le paquet gstreamer1.0-doc n'est pas installé.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet midieditor (--install) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 midieditor
vincent@vincent-laptop:~/Applications/MidiEditor$
```

It seems that some packages are no longer available on my Ubuntu version.

I've made a fake qt5-default according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335184/qt5-default-not-in-ubuntu-21-04). I've installed the other packages. Only remain lacking gstreamer1.0-doc

```
vincent@vincent-laptop:~/Applications/MidiEditor$ sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-doc
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait      
Aucune version du paquet gstreamer1.0-doc n'est disponible, mais il existe dans la base
de données. Cela signifie en général que le paquet est manquant, qu'il est devenu obsolète
ou qu'il n'est disponible que sur une autre source

E: Le paquet « gstreamer1.0-doc » n'a pas de version susceptible d'être installée
vincent@vincent-laptop:~/Applications/MidiEditor$
```

But Gstreamer seams allready installed :

```
vincent@vincent-laptop:~/Applications/MidiEditor$ gst-inspect-1.0 --version
gst-inspect-1.0 version 1.20.3
GStreamer 1.20.3
https://launchpad.net/distros/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer1.0
vincent@vincent-laptop:~/Applications/MidiEditor$
```

I have tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340794/is-gstreamer-available-for-ubuntu-21-04-and-if-it-is-then-how-to-install-it). But I still get :

```
vincent@vincent-laptop:~/Applications/MidiEditor$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-doc
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait      
Aucune version du paquet gstreamer1.0-doc n'est disponible, mais il existe dans la base
de données. Cela signifie en général que le paquet est manquant, qu'il est devenu obsolète
ou qu'il n'est disponible que sur une autre source

E: Le paquet « gstreamer1.0-doc » n'a pas de version susceptible d'être installée
vincent@vincent-laptop:~/Applications/MidiEditor$
```

Which way to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [fake empty](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/HackingDependencies) `qstream1.0-doc` package as well :

`gstreamer1.0-doc`

```
Package: gstreamer1.0-doc
Version: 99:99
Maintainer: Your Name <mail@domain.com>
Architecture: all
Description: dummy gstreamer1.0-doc package
 A dummy package with a version number so high that the real gnome packages
 will never reach it.
```

Then run

```
sudo equivs-build gstreamer1.0-doc
sudo apt-get install ./gstreamer1.0-doc_99_all.deb
```

Turns out gstreamer1.0-doc is just for [the gstream documentation](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-docs/-/issues/101), and it doesn't seem to be in use anywhere in the app.
I spoofed both `qt5-default` with the method you cite and `qstream1.0-doc` with this empty package, and I was able to `apt install midieditor`. I browsed the app and everything seems to be working properly (you still need to setup your midi environment but this is another story)